# What does *(&a)=5 mean?

Tags: c++, c++11

I’m studying about pointers. It’s quite confusing—maybe because I’m new. I have a question that what `*(&a)` indicates in the following short program.

On line 7, I know `*(&a)` means “value at address of variable `a`,” but on line 13, what does `*(&a)=5` mean? When I assign `&a=5`, the compiler gives an error along the lines of “lvalue required as left operand of assignment,” but when I assign the value in `*(&a)`, then it compiles with no error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int *p, a = 2, b;

  b = *(&a);         // line 7
  printf("%d", b);

  p = &a;
  printf("%d", p);

  *(&a) = 5;         // line 13
  printf("%d", a);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: &a returns address of variable, * means dereferencing, so I think *(&a) = 2 is the same as a = 5

Comment: `&a` returns the address of `a`. `*(&a)` dereferences that address. So `*(&a)` first looks at `a`, takes its address with `&`, and then dereferences this address with `*`, allowing for assignment.

Comment: `*(&a)` is the same as `a`

Comment: @IvanKuckir ITYM `*(&a) = 5` is the same as `a = 5`

Answer (score 1):

Given an `int a;` then `&a` gives you the address of `a` which is an `int *`. Given an `int *p;` the expression `*p` gives you the `int` that `p` is pointing to. So `*(&a)` is the value behind the address of `a` which is `a`. In other words `*(&a)` does the same as just `a`.

There are times when this is sort of useful. Given a `std::vector<int>::iterator it;` you can get a pointer to the `int` the iterator points to by dereferencing the iterator to get the `int` and then take the address, so you get `&(*it)`.

Comment: `&*` is a different kettle of fish to `*&` (especially if applied to a class type)

Answer (score 0):

`&a` will return a pointer to a, or the memory address where `a` is located.  The dereference operator `*` returns the value of the data pointed to by the address.  Consider the following code.

```
int foo = 3;
int* bar = &foo; /// bar points to foo.
printf( "%d\n", *bar ); /// will print 3
printf( "%d\n", *(&foo) ); /// will also print 3
```

The variable `bar` points to the memory address where `foo` is located.  By using the dereference operator, you get the value stored in memory at the address contained in `bar`.  The last example combines the two, you get a pointer to `foo` and immediately dereference it, which returns the value stored in `foo`

Comment: @csnate thankyou for my question's reply . i want to ask a question that how &a is a pointer i mean a pointer is that which store location of any other variable.And also what does derefernce mean here? please explain it will be realy kind of you! :)

Comment: I will update to answer to be more accurate as @nwp is correct.  Its a pointer.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in § 5.3.1 [expr.unary.op]:

> 1 The unary * operator performs *indirection*: the expression to which
>   it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a
>   function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or
>   function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression
>   is “pointer to T,” the type of the result is “T.”

and:

> 2 The result of each of the following unary operators is a prvalue.
>
> 3 The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand.

Since `&a` yields a [`prvalue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), `&a = 5` is invalid, because `&a` is not an lvalue. Only modifiable lvalues can appear on the left hand of the built-in assignment operator.

On the other hand, `*(&a)` yields an lvalue (making it assignable).